# How to use Shortcuts to block the caller of spam text?

Tags: iphone, automation, spam

It's an election year, so I'm getting a ton of spam messages.  If I don't block the number, I get even more.  When a message appears, it takes 13 steps to block the caller and delete the message.  (Holy moly, Apple, you gotta streamline that!)  Is there a way to use the Shortcuts app to build an automation on my phone to do that quicker?

Comment: Most carriers have a text spam number, AT&T is 7726. I just forward spam texts to that and then delete the text. Works and those spammers don't show up again.

Comment: Just to note that 7726 is the UK number too, any carrier. [it spells SPAM on the dialler letters].

Comment: I didn't know about 7726.  Thanks for the tip.